# How to add a specific library beside the JDK into IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In a file of a big old project written mainly by jdk1.3 there is a file which imports `javax.imageio`. When I make the project in IntelliJ I receive the following error:

```
 Error:(10, 1) java: package javax.imageio does not exist
```

I can't change the base SDK of the project which is jdk1.3, how can I add this particular library to the project in IntelliJ?

I am almost new to java and am testing this project. I even don't know where can I find `imageio`, I found one in jdk1.8 src.zip and tried to add it to project via `Project Structure > Libraries` but I still get the error.

Comment: *how can I add this particular library to the project in IntelliJ?* Download and install [JAI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jai-142803.html). And the project has a [github](https://github.com/jai-imageio/jai-imageio-core).

Comment: You tried to backport a 1.8 library to 1.3? That certainly would not work the way you expect

Comment: Also, your Java version is [**old enough to drive**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.3). Upgrade.